# Peter Lax Functional Analysis exercise

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ denote a Banach space, $A$ a bounded linear map: $X \to X$. Let $\{M_{v}\}$ be a collection of bounded maps from $X$ to itself such that, $\forall x\in X,$  $AM_{v}x=M_{v}Ax$ (That is, the map $A$ conmutes with every $M_{v}$). Show that A conmutes with every bounded linear map belonging to the closed linear span of the set $\{M_{v}\}$ in the weak topology.

Earlier in the book he defines:

The weak topology in $L(X,U)$ is the topology generated by the functions of the form $M \to Mx$, $\forall x\in X$ (i.e, the weakest topology in wich all such linear maps are continuous).

I am able to prove that the result is true in the linear span (Just use linearity). But how can I extend to the weak closure? I don't even know if this topology is first countable, or sequential (If so, I can do it, too). And I wasn't able to prove it or give a counterexample.

Comment: The so called weak topology on $L(X,U)$ is actually the [strong operator topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_operator_topology), it is generated by a [separated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_convex_topological_vector_space#Further_definitions_and_properties) family of seminorms. So it's a Hausdorff locally convex space, and you can apply the net convergence argument...

Comment: Do you have any source where I can read more about that argument?

Comment: Sure, [Conway' book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ccEGCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA377&lpg=PA377&dq=functional+analysis+conway+%22A+net+in+X+is+a+pair+%22&source=bl&ots=pmFtAKPUPa&sig=B39jZTqpXSDOKDilgUHiRn-S4lQ&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ58HV6KPZAhUmxoMKHcLNC1QQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=functional%20analysis%20conway%20%22A%20net%20in%20X%20is%20a%20pair%20%22&f=false) for instant. You can also find the notion strong/weak operator topology here. Net is a generalization of sequence, so the argument is basically similar to sequential convergence argument. Hausdorff property is to ensure the limit is unique

Comment: What do you mean by 'functions of the form $M \to Mx$'?

Comment: Define $F_{x} : L(X,U) \to U$ which takes a map $M$ and sends it to $Mx$, and then define the topology generated by this set of functions.. As you can see, this is not the "normal" weak topology, in the sense that we are not dealing with funtionals

Comment: What is $U$? ${}{}$

Comment: Sorry, in this case $X=U$

Comment: In any event, the same idea as below applies with a little twist. The intersection of a collection of closed sets is still closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\phi \in X^*$, then $\phi_1,\phi_2$ defined by $\phi_1(M) = \phi(AM), \phi_2(M) = \phi(MA)$ are also in $X^*$.

We see that $(\phi_1-\phi_2)(M) = 0$ for all $M \in \operatorname{sp} \{ M_v\}$.

It follows that $(\phi_1-\phi_2)(M) = 0$ for all $M \in \overline{\operatorname{sp}^w} \{ M_v\}$ (weak closure).

It follows from this that $AM-MA = 0$.

**Note**: There is a simpler proof based on the fact that a convex set is strongly closed **iff** it is weakly closed.

**Addendum**:
If $M \in \overline{\operatorname{sp}^w} \{ M_v\}$, then if $C$ is any weakly closed set containing $\operatorname{sp} \{ M_v\}$, we must have $M \in C$.

The set $\ker (\phi_1-\phi_2)$ is a weakly closed set that contains $\operatorname{sp} \{ M_v\}$,
hence $\overline{\operatorname{sp}^w} \{ M_v\} \subset \ker (\phi_1-\phi_2)$.

**More stuff**: Since the weak topology is defined slightly differently we adapt the approach above:

Choose $x$ and define $\phi_{x}(M) = (AM-MA)x$. Then $\ker \phi_x$ is weakly closed for all $x$ and so $C=\cap_x \ker \phi_x$ is weakly closed. We see that $M \in C$ **iff** $AM=MA$.

We see that $M_v \in C$ for all $v$, hence $\overline{\operatorname{sp}^w} \{ M_v\}  \subset C$.

Comment: I don't get the final part, when you pass to the weak closure.

Comment: @Rhcpy99: I added an elaboration.

Comment: Why is that kernel a weak closed set in this sense?

Comment: With the different version of weak closed, you need to consider functionals of the form $\phi(M) = AMx$ (and similar for $MAx$). The kernel of $\phi_1-\phi_2$ is weakly closed by definition. Hence the intersection over all $x$ is closed. Hence we obtain the same result.

Comment: I added a few more lines to my answer to elaborate.

Comment: I think now I understand your idea. I must write everything down in details what you showed me.